# FolderBrowserDialog disable OK if file does not exist

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

I am opening a FolderBrowserDialog for the user to select a folder.  However I only want the user to be able to select folders that have an XML file in it.  Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Comment: No easy way - you would need to derive from `FolderBrowserDialog` and implement it yourself, but that class is `sealed`. You'll need to roll your own from scratch, in my opinion.

Comment: @RogerRowland I was thinking this was the case but hoping I was wrong.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why don't you just re-display it when you find out that the folder doesn't contain any .xml files?  Easy peasy.

Comment: @HansPassant that is an option but I decided to display a message "No XML files found" for now then look at writing my own when I have more time.